# How to resolve error could not get lock

Tags: java, installation

```
piyush@piyush-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

Comment: Have you gone through this from the ubuntu forum? 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/15433/unable-to-lock-the-administration-directory-var-lib-dpkg-is-another-process

Comment: Could you describe what were you doing when you get the error? What did you do until there?